# Using ‘this’ as scope when creating $ionicModal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I seem to be having an issue creating an `$ionicModal` when trying to specify my scope as `this` instead of `$scope`.

Since I'm binding everything in my controller via an instance name, I'm not using `$scope` inside of the controller.

So, I initiate the modal as instructed here in [Ionic Framework doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)
and switched `$scope` with `this`

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: this,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    this.modal = modal;
  });
```

When the app runs, I get the following error:

> undefined is not a function

and it references the following code in **ionic.bundle.js**:

```
var createModal = function(templateString, options) {
    // Create a new scope for the modal
    var scope = options.scope && options.scope.$new() || $rootScope.$new(true);
```

I even tried assigning another variable to represent `this` and running it that way, but the same error prevails!

If I'm not using `$scope` in my controller, what would be the best way to load a modal while maintaining the usage of `this`? Is it just not possible or am I missing something?

**EDIT-**
As requested, adding more info to the original,

**Template:**

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<button ng-click="ctrl.demo()">Demo Button</button>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('MyDemo', ['ionic'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($ionicModal) {
var _this = this;
this.demo = function () {
//do demo related stuff here
}

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
        scope: _this,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
        _this.modal = modal;
      });
});
```

So, basically, I'm using the 1st declaration style found here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

EDIT: Changed `this` to `_this` inside of `$ionicModal`

As requested, here's a plunker with the code above:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4GbulCDgoj4iZtmAg6v3?p=info

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Since I'm binding everything in my controller via an instance name", can you show us more of your controller code or even better, a sample plunker where the error occurs?

Comment: Added some more info to the original. I guess, the question is, can 'this' be used instead of $scope when setting up a modal..

Comment: have you tried assigning `this` to self? For example, `var self = this;` then use `scope: self`

Comment: Yep, sure did. I like to use _this as opposed to self, but yea that didn't work either.

Comment: I wonder if it's this in ionic.bundle.js that's throwing it off: options.scope.$new which would be the same as, this.$new

Comment: The only thing that I can think may cause the issue is that when that code is being called, the original scope object isn't available anymore -- but without a working sample that I can actually test/debug I don't think that I can help (and I don't know ionic well enough to create a quick sample).

Comment: Added a plunker link

Comment: Apparently when using the controller as syntax, the `this` scope object doesn't have the `$new()` function, that is your problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because of how AngularJs currently sets up the controller when using the "controller as" syntax, you only have whatever functions and properties that you yourself define in the controller function.  In order to access the [$new()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new) function that AngularJs provides to create child scopes, you need to provide an AngularJs `$scope` object -- which you can still get by getting it injected into your constructor function, even when using the "controller as" syntax.

```
angular.module('MyDemo', ['ionic'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal) {
  var _this = this;
  this.demo = function () {
    //do demo related stuff here
  }

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    _this.modal = modal;
  });
});
```

Comment: I posted this question on the ionic forum as well and received somewhat of the same response, but this one is even simpler. Thanks for helping me through it yesterday, much appreciated!